# Google map with many markers wait till all markers are fully loaded

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-maps, listener, google-maps-markers

I have a Google map in which I load several markers from an Ajax page as following. Since the markers may be many (up to 2000) I would like to add some sort of overlay div to the map to indicate loading process.

```
  var map;
  var markers = []; 
  var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
  function initialize() { //initialize the map and specify map options
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 6,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(48,13),
      mapTypeId: 'terrain' 
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
   }
```

To do so I initially added a jquery function (`$('#overlay').show();`) at the beginning of my AJAX jquery function to make the div visible. That seem to work fine. My problem is that when I set the corresponding hide function ( `$('#overlay').hide();`) at the end of the jquery function, the div disappears before all markers are fully loaded. Is it possible to wait till the map has properly loaded all (2000) markers?

```
  var resultsArr = new Array();
  var n = 0;
  var f = function () { 
    n++;
    $('#overlay').show(); //div overlaying at the beginning of the function
    $.ajax({
      url: "ajax_page.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: {func: 'getLocation'},
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        resultsArr.push(data);

        for (var i=0; i<markers.length; i++) {
          markers[i].setMap(null);
        }
        markers = [];
        addmarkersfromarray(resultsArr); 
       $('#overlay').hide(); //my problem
      }
    });
```

Following is the addmarkersfromarray function. I have seen that a possible soution could be to add an event listener (like `google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'tilesloaded', fullyloaded);`) on the map to check when it finished loading but I don't understand how I should set it.

```
  function addmarkersfromarray(locations) {
    arraywise = locations[0]; 
    numberofevents = arraywise.length; 
    for (var i = 0; i < numberofevents; i++ ) { 
      var metricswise = locations[0][i];
      var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(metricswise.latitude, metricswise.longitude);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map, 
        title: metricswise.location, 
        icon: {
          path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
          fillOpacity: 0.5,
          fillColor: '#ff0000',
          strokeOpacity: 0.3,
          strokeColor: '#fff000',
          strokeWeight: 1.0, 
          scale: 4
        }    
      });
//??//??//??//??//??//??//??//??//??//??//??//??
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'tilesloaded', fullyloaded); 
            function fullyloaded() {
              alert("helllo");
              $('#overlay').hide();
            }
//??//??//??//??//??//??//??//??//??//??//??//??          
      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
        return function () {
          var metricswise = locations[0][i];
          var contentString = 'this is an infowindow ';
          infowindow.setContent(contentString);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, i));
      markers.push(marker);
    }
  }
```

Comment: `$.ajax` provides this functionality. Just add `beforeSend:` which enables the overlay and indicate the loading process and in you `success/ done` function you simply remove it. Then it´s just some line of CSS for the overlay or use some lib like spin.js for it

Comment: actually my function is working correctly, the problem is that I cannot define the moment at which all 2000 markers have loaded. All the ajax and the functions shown terminate so the div disappear but the 2000 markers still have to finish loading.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? I'm experiencing same problem.